# Getting Last Value in Group Concat

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
course     chapter          lessons

  2        Chapter1          3,4
  2        Chapter2          5,10,9,6,8
  2        Chapter3          11,15,16,18
```

I need the last value in lessons column like 
In the 1st row of lessons i need the last digit 4
In the 2nd row of lessons i need the last digit 8
In the 3rd row of lessons i need the last digit 18

Comment: Is this a base table or one produced by a query?

Comment: [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) Short answer: **Yes, it is**.

Comment: Until you normalize, use `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(lessons, ',', -1) FROM table`. Check [String functions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: @ypercube: Why are the above 2 comments and not answers?  You have it... `Select course, chapter, lessons, substring_Index(Lessons,',',-1) as LastLesson from table`

Comment: Hello ypercube, what;s there to be bad in showing group_concat?

Comment: xQbert: OK, I'll bite :)

Comment: @ronquiq: Either it's a base table (and it's bad, really bad design) or the output of a query that uses `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) Short answer: Yes, it is.

But until you normalize the table, you could use this:

```
SELECT course 
     , chapter
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(lessons, ',', -1) AS last_lesson
FROM tableX
```